# How come there are hundreds of users with the same name?

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, display-names

I've just noticed there are probably hundreds of users with exactly the same username on StackOverflow.

Why does SO allow username conflicts? That makes no sense [search username 'Artur'](https://stackoverflow.com/users)

Comment: What is the problem? If my name would have been Artur, why would I need to choose a different name than yours? Focus is on content anyway. Not on users. P.s. not a bug. [status-by-design]

Comment: @Bart: Show me the site where you can have 100 users with the same username. That's a problem - usernames like emails are suppossed to be unique

Comment: @Artur There's your problem. They're not usernames. They're display names.

Comment: @Artur no they are not.

Comment: What is the problem though? Can't find a specific user? Get confused between users? Who cares. It's the content that matters.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all&search=troll](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all&search=troll)

Comment: My question is why most sites *don't* allow duplicate display names, rather than why SE *does* allow it.

Comment: RichardTingle735 thinks the real world manages so we'll probably be fine too

Comment: @RichardTingle you should change your name to that :-)

Answer (score 14):

There are hundreds of users whose parents gave them the name of Artur.

Display names are not supposed to be unique.

> Show me the site where you can have 100 users with the same username

http://facebook.com

Comment: Not true.  They have the same display names, but not the same username.  This woman's display name is Mimi Kirk, but her username is a Mimi-Kirk.  That is a unique username.  https://www.facebook.com/pages/Mimi-Kirk/109888045694543

Comment: @JohnyBones our equivalent to that is our OpenID, which is different for everyone here too

Comment: @johnny bones. The question was ill-posed in the first place. Saying "usernames" the OP was actually referring to display names.

Comment: I sense a reversal badge coming...